# How can I improve my question which I am looking for a simple/trivial answer to?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[Reimplementing hexchat's XText's hidden text in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50657918/reimplementing-hexchats-xtexts-hidden-text-in-html)

I can't tell what's wrong with it at all, all I can tell is that ppl want it closed/removed.

Comment: A better question I suppose would show the concrete results obtained from your own searches made prior to asking, and then use these results to make the question more specific. Better still would be to show your best attempt at a solution in the question and tell the details on how it doesn't work well for you. Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: It is a very unusual requirement, you cannot assume it is going to be "simple/trivial".  Be sure to explain the reason why you need this to work, best odds to get SO users to think along with you and propose a completely different approach.  Narrowing it down to a specific browser and OS might help as well.

Answer (score 6):

It's a bit unfair to presume that your solution is simple or trivial, given what you're asking has a few shortcomings:

- It's unclear what your criteria are.  You mention screen readers in the comments but not in the body of the question, which introduces ambiguity and confusion.
- Until [very recently](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/50657918/4), you hadn't indicated what behavior you were trying to copy.
- Even [more recently](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/50657918/5), you hadn't shown any of your own attempts at solving this problem, either.
- Fundamentally, it's not certain if you're amenable to solutions that do this in HTML, CSS *and* JavaScript, or if you're only looking to do this in HTML and CSS.  That raises the barrier of entry to people looking to help solve your problem.

To be blunt, your question got off on the wrong foot.  It's slightly better now, but I personally would still think it's too broad since it kind of reads like a set of requirements for us to fulfill.

Comment: There isn't a no-js tag.

Comment: @SoniEx2:  You could specify it in the question directly.